# Button event not working while image is moving

Tags: java, image, swing

i have this code. in this code an image is moving left to right with moveImage method and moves right to left with moveimg method in the code. what i want now is to work a button event. there is a button in code, i want when i click the button it should do its job. but it's not doing.. here the code is:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyImage extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   static int xPixel = 20;
   Image myImage, offScreenImage;
   Graphics offScreenGraphics;
   JPanel p = new JPanel();
   Button btn = new Button("bun");
   JFrame f = new JFrame();

   public MyImage()
   {
      myImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("mywineshoplogo.jpg");
      setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
      add(p);
      p.add(btn);
      moveImage();
      btn.addActionListener(this);
   }

   public void update(Graphics g)
   {
      paint(g);
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      int width = getWidth();
      int height = getHeight();
      if (offScreenImage == null)
      {
         offScreenImage = createImage(width, height);
         offScreenGraphics = offScreenImage.getGraphics();
      }
// clear the off screen image  
      offScreenGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, width + 1, height + 1);
// draw your image off screen  
      offScreenGraphics.drawImage(myImage, xPixel, 10, this);
// draw your image off screen  
// show the off screen image  
      g.drawImage(offScreenImage, 0, 0, this);
// show the off screen image  
   }

   void moveImage()   //left to right move
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < 530; i++)
      {

         xPixel += 1;
         repaint();
        // then sleep for a bit for your animation  
         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(40);
         } /* this will pause for 50 milliseconds */

         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {
            System.err.println("sleep exception");
         }
      }
   }

/*   void moveimg()   // right to left move
   {
      for (int i = 529; i > 0; i--)
      {
         if (i == 1)
         {
            moveImage();
         }
         xPixel -= 1;
         repaint();
// then sleep for a bit for your animation  
         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(40);
         } // this will pause for 50 milliseconds 

         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {
            System.err.println("sleep exception");
          }
      } 
   } */     

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
      try
      {
         if (ae.getSource() == btn)
         {
            p.setBackground(Color.RED);
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("error");
      }
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      MyImage me = new MyImage();
   }
}
```

Comment: Code should be put in the question, not simply linked to. And it should be properly indented. And you should remember to add a tag indicating the language. Fixed.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to do that.. i am new here...

Comment: To put the code in the question is a simple copy-paste. To have it be formatted, select the code and click the `{}` button at the top of the edit box or press Ctrl-K or manually prefix every line with 4 spaces. To have it indented you'll have to use an external program or do it manually. On the [edit] page, you can also add tags at the bottom.

Comment: manually it's difficult. can you tell me any external program?

Comment: Any decent IDE in the language you're programming in (Java in this case) should be able to properly indent / format code. In e.g. [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) you click Source -> Format. I'm sure there are programs that have this functionality but aren't an entire IDE, but I'm not too familiar with any, you may have success [Googling for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+beautifier+-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You should port animations to their own thread. This will stop your main thread locking up due to other processes. You're calling `Thread.sleep(40);` on the main thread. This will invariably effect the throughput of your one and only thread.

**A solution**

So, you should create a new class, say `ImageMover`. This class could take the Image object in it's constructor and have a method `moveImage` to move the image, as opposed to your solution of `moveImg` and `moveImage` (very confusing stuff).

Secondly, you want to have `ImageMover` extend a `Thread`. This will force you to write a `run` method, which will look something like this:

```
public void run() {
    moveImage();
}
```

When you want your image to start moving, you should call `ImageMover.start()`. 
**NOT** `run`.

This will place the method on a different thread, and should ensure the functionality of your GUI.

Comment: moveImage() for left to right and moveImg() for right to left move.

Comment: Do you think that is an appropriate naming system?

Comment: Did you try porting your code into a different thread like I suggested?

Comment: yes i did, but it's not working. how i can show you my new code?

Comment: You can edit the original question and put your new code into it.

Comment: can you mail me the correct code? i am new here and i dont about this forum much..

Comment: @BhargavVijraj Trying to get someone else' answer to work is a slightly different scenario to posting a question. In this case, I believe it is acceptable to link to code stored on an external source, as you originally did with the question, http://pastebin.com/ is a pretty decent way to do this, https://ideone.com/ is nice since it's a compiler as well (but I think it won't work with a GUI). Mailing around code is not really appropriate for this site.

Comment: okay i got it... as i said i am new here so dont know how to link or something else... but i will improve it..

Comment: named it Mover not ImageMover

Comment: Well then why is this there: `ImageMover.start();`?

Comment: I never said `ImageMover.start();`. I said you call the `start` method of an `ImageMover` object. You've called it `Mover`, so you need to create a new `Mover` object, and call the start method of *that object*. Not it's class.

Comment: what changes should be made now??

Comment: Why not post the stack trace of those errors? Try to clean up your question a little so other people can help you. :)

Comment: I could, but that would defy the point of a learning process. We're not here to write code for you.

Comment: MyImage.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
         xPixel += 1;
         ^
  symbol:   variable xPixel
  location: class Mover
MyImage.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
         repaint();
         ^
  symbol:   method repaint()
  location: class Mover
2 errors

Comment: i put paint and update methods in Mover class but giving errors because paint and update methods are requiring extends JPanel but in the code Mover class is extending Thread class. if i put paint and update methods in MyImage class then errors above occurs... please help me out this problem...

Comment: please check it.. i have edited the code now.. tell me what to do now..?